# gradle command line properties for subprojects

Tags: command-line, properties, gradle

I have a multiproject gradle build whose top level has the following:

```groovy
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'war'
  httpPort = hasProperty('jettyPort') ? jettyPort.toInteger() : 8080
}
```

If I run from the command line `gradle -PjettyPort=9000 war` the call to `hasProperty` returns `null`, but if I move the `hasProperty` check outside the `subprojects` closure, then it returns `true`.

Is this the designed behavior or should I be able to access the properties from `subprojects` closure as I tried above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work?

```groovy
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'war'
  httpPort = project.hasProperty('jettyPort') ? jettyPort.toInteger() : 8080
}
```

Comment: It must be that without using project.hasProperty, it implies root.hasProptery or something like that.